# How to automatically copy and paste cells Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

My goal is to write information in one column, and have it duplicated to another column. Lets say I have my data in cell =A3. I would like this data to automatically be copied into cell =Z50. The only way I know to do this without manually and writing the data or copy and pasting the cells is to go to cell =Z50 and in the function bar set it equal to =A3. I was hoping someone might know of a way to automate this process. By setting the column Z equal to the A column with the same row.

Comment: Use the `onEdit(e)` simple trigger.  [Link to Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing, and even though I haven't tried the ArrayFormula solution, this could be another way to get this automatically copying done:

`=QUERY(MySheet!B1:B100,"SELECT *")`

Use this formula where you have planned to get the information copied.

`"MySheet!B1:B100"` = This will be the sheet you want to get data copied from.

`"SELECT *"` = This will get everything in this interval copied, in case you want any specific data into the interval, you have the option of choosing as well.

I found this tip at: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/31xTcOHNRJM

Comment: I found this post usefulland researching found this Google Visualization API Query Language syntax tutorial to understand the method: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax

Answer (score 0):

This formula might work in cell Z50 (or anywhere else on the sheet that you want the data copied to):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,A3:A))`